# I need to compare two Tables in Access for 2 characteristics and 1 KF

Tags: ms-access

TBL 1

```
PK   AK   TOT1    
1    1    100    
2    2    200    
2    2    300     
3    3    100
3    3     10
```

TBL 2

```
PK   AK   TOT1   
1    1     50     
2    2     50     
2    2     100    
4    2     50     
3    3    100
3    3     10
```

I need to compare T1 and T2 and find non match values.

Result

```
PK AK t1.Sum(Tot1)  t2.sum(tot1)
1   1   100             50
2   2   500             150
4   2    0              50
```

Comment: what database are you using ? please choose one you cannot ask this for 3 different databases

Comment: I have mentioned Access Database..

Comment: I had an answer but it is for sql server. So I deleted it.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks :) ...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Could you have a read of these links please:  [ask] and [mcve].  Also Access has a built in _Find Unmatched Query Wizard_ which will do the job.

Comment: Hi Darren ..I tried wizard but no luck... And trust me I have googled it a lot searched stack overflow but found nothing..

Comment: If you've tried a lot, show your closest attempt, plus what's not working. Then we likely can help you from there

Comment: This query is able to bring aggregate results from the second table, but when i apply the aggregation to the fist table then the result is not proper.


Select A.P, A.C , k,2,  T2.K3
FROM A  INNER JOIN
     (SELECT B.P1, B.C1, SUM(K1) as K3
      FROM  B 
GROUP BY B.P1,B.C1
     ) T2
     ON (A.P = T2.P1) AND (A.C = T2.C1)
WHERE A.K <> T2.K3

Comment: Don't understand example data. How can a PK field have duplicate values? Looks like need to build two aggregate queries then compare the two aggregates in a 'Find Unmatched' query.